# Strip <p> inside of <p> wrapper

Tags: php, strip

Im not sure what to look for to try to achieve this but I was trying to do a str_replace to all the `<p>` tags and replace them with `<br/>` and it worked but then I releaized I need to wrap the content with `<p>`

this is the code i used

```
<?php
      $nodecontent = render($content);
      $newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $nodecontent);
      $newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br /><br />", $newcontent);
  print render($newcontent);
?>
```

this is what my my content had before

```
  <div property="content:encoded" class="field-item even">
<p>SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..<p>SOME TExT HERE</p> and here and <p>Here..SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..</p>
</p>
</div>
```

then after I put the code in it looks like this so it did work to some degree but stripped the `<p>` tag

```
    <div property="content:encoded" class="field-item even">
SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..<br/><br/>SOME TExT HERE<br/><br/> and here and <br/><br/>Here..SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..<br/><br/>
</div>
```

but i want it to look like this without stripping the `<p>` tag as a wrapper

```
   <div property="content:encoded" class="field-item even"><p>
        SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..<br/><br/>SOME TExT HERE<br/><br/> and here and <br/><br/>Here..SOME TExT HERE and here and Here..<br/><br/>
        </p></div>
```

Comment: Cannot resist... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: -_- well thats why im here for guidance, and i get down voted, my code worked partially...

Comment: and your link doesnt even help...

Comment: Behavior like this is why we get pages like this: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=stackoverflow+sucks&pbx=1&oq=stackoverflow+sucks&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1931l7078l0l7604l15l15l0l2l2l0l393l2502l0.8.4.1l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f51f088013f93507&biw=1024&bih=531

Comment: What does **render** do in `$nodecontent = render($content);`

Comment: it echos out the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

between jquery and php i figured this out, not thanks to the others who criticized me and down voted me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".field-item").wrapInner('<p></p>')
    });
    </script>

    <?php $nodecontent = render($content);
      $newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $nodecontent);
      $newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "<br /><br />", $newcontent);

 print render($newcontent); ?>
```